# How to infer hasMandatoryHours property

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I'm working on an ontology in which I have that:

`Course isPartOf CourseGroup`

And a Course has a boolean property `isMandatory` and a numerical property `hasHours`.

So a `CourseGroup` is made out of a group of courses some of which are mandatory, and all of the individuals of the `Course` class have a value on the hasHours property.

Now I want to answer the question: **How many hours of mandatory courses are teached on `CourseGroup` x?**

How would you do that? Would it be just a query of should I set a `hasMandatoryHours` property for `CourseGroup` that would be calculated as the sum of the `hasHours` of Courses where `isMandatory` is true?

Any thoughts or examples on how this is done for other ontologies will be appreciated.

Comment: Either SPARQL or SWRL. And never forget, OWL reasoning is monotonic, i.e. once you added such a sum value explicitly, any inference won't update the previous value but just add a new inferred one.

Comment: SPARQL plugin doesn't support update queries, and there is no `swrlb:sum` builtin... I'm afraid, this is impossible in Protege.

Comment: @StanislavKralin but I could get the answer for this question using SPARQL for a given time, right? Without it updating a value or anything, just the plain answer

Comment: @moondaisy, Ah, OK, sorry! BTW, it seems that `CONSTRUCT` is supported.

Comment: @StanislavKralin don't worry, I wanted to know all the available possibilities. What is `CONSTRUCT`? (it's a broad term, so it's hard to google).

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#construct . This is not another possibility, this is just a way to get a triple, not a number.